# Curve fitting for the function type : y =10^((a-x)/10*b)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Below is a distance calculated (column `y`) based on values from sensor (column `x`).

#### test.txt - contents

```
x   y   
----------


-51.61  ,1.5
-51.61  ,1.5
-51.7   ,1.53
-51.91  ,1.55
-52.28  ,1.62
-52.35  ,1.63
-52.49  ,1.66
-52.78  ,1.71
-52.84  ,1.73
-52.90  ,1.74
-53.21  ,1.8
-53.43  ,1.85
-53.55  ,1.87
-53.71  ,1.91
-53.99  ,1.97
-54.13  ,2
-54.26  ,2.03
-54.37  ,2.06
-54.46  ,2.08
-54.59  ,2.11
-54.89  ,2.19
-54.94  ,2.2
-55.05  ,2.23
-55.11  ,2.24
-55.17  ,2.26
```

I would like to curve fit to find the constants `a` and `b` for the data in `test.txt` based on this function:

```
Function y = 10^((a-x)/10*b)
```

I use the following code:

```
import math

from numpy import genfromtxt  
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

inData = genfromtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',')

rssi_data = inData[:,0]
dist_data= inData[:,1]

print rssi_data
print dist_data

def func(x, a,b):
    exp_val = (x-a)/(10.0*b) 
    return math.pow(10,exp_val)

coeffs, matcov = curve_fit(func,rssi_data,dist_data)

print(coeffs)
print(matcov)
```

The code does not execute successfully. Also I'm not sure if I'm passing the right parameters to `curve_fit()`.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Change `math.pow(10, exp_val)` to `10**exp_val`.

Comment: The above change seems to work , can you please elaborate why  ?

Comment: `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` expects a function that can take a `numpy` array as its first argument, and your `func` does not because `math.pow` does not.

Comment: Why not take the log10 in both sides and fit a straight line? :o

Answer (score 5):

The function will need to process numpy-arrays but currently it can't because `math.pow` expects a scalar value. If I execute your code I get this Exception:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

If you change your function to:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return 10 ** ((a - x) / (10 * b))  # ** is the power operator
```

It should work without exceptions:

```
>>> print(coeffs)
[-48.07485338   2.00667587]
>>> print(matcov)
[[  3.59154631e-04   1.21357926e-04]
 [  1.21357926e-04   4.25732516e-05]]
```

Here the complete code:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return 10 ** ((a - x) / (10 * b))

coeffs, matcov = curve_fit(func, rssi_data, dist_data)

# And some plotting for visualization

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook  # only works in IPython notebooks

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(rssi_data, dist_data, label='measured')
x = np.linspace(rssi_data.min(), rssi_data.max(), 1000)
plt.plot(x, func(x, coeffs[0], coeffs[1]), label='fitted')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the previous answer, as it is the correct one for the programming problem. But looking closer, you don't need to do the power law fitting:

```
y = 10^((a-x)/10*b) <=> log10(y) = log10(10^((a-x)/10*b)) 
<=> log10(y) = (a-x)/10*b
```

Use new variables:

```
z = log10(y), c = a/10*b and d = -1/10*b
```

And you have to fit now the following:

```
z = dx + c
```

Which is a straight line. Well, you just need to apply the above transformations to 2 points (x,y) => (x,log10(y)) in your table and fit a straight line to get c,d and therefore a,b.

I'm writing this because maybe you have to do this many times and this is much simpler (and precise) to do than fitting a power function.It has consequences too when you plan your experiment. You essentially need just 2 points to get the general behavior if you know this is the correct fitting function.

I hope this helps.  Cheers!